# Sort PHP array by numerical values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort the following names

```
Array ( [Jessie] => 2 [Sarah] => 3 [Simon] => 2 [John] => 2 [Kevin] => 1 [Canvasser] => 8 [canvasser] => 11 )
```

based on the values corresponding to them

I printed the names through the following function

```
// get canvasser individual names and count houses canvassed
    foreach ($canvassers as $key => $value) {
        // Add to the current group count if it exists
        if ( isset( $canvasser_counts[$value] ) ) {
            $canvasser_counts[$value]++;
        }
        // or initialize to 1 if it doesn't exist
        else {
            $canvasser_counts[$value] = 1;
        }
    }
    print_r($canvasser_counts);
```

where $canvassers simply held all the names eg.

```
$canvassers = array('Jessie', 'Simon', 'Jessie')
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I have spent so long on this but can't get my head straight to sort the array correctly.

Comment: asort might help here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php but I am unsure of what ordering you want, maybe you can define that

Comment: the question is to sort "based on the values corresponding to them," so `asort()` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @doublesharp What if he wants to sort in arsort() "based on the values corresponding to them," ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use `asort()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php - to sort the values in ascending order, or `arsort()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php - to sort in descending order.

Given this PHP:

```
$vals = array("Jessie" => 2, "Sara" => 3, "Simon" => 2, "John" => 2, "Kevin" => 1, "Canvasser" => 8, "canvasser" => 11 );
print_r($vals); // current order
asort($vals); // sort array
print_r($vals); // new order
```

You will get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [Jessie] => 2
    [Sara] => 3
    [Simon] => 2
    [John] => 2
    [Kevin] => 1
    [Canvasser] => 8
    [canvasser] => 11
)
Array
(
    [Kevin] => 1
    [Jessie] => 2
    [John] => 2
    [Simon] => 2
    [Sara] => 3
    [Canvasser] => 8
    [canvasser] => 11
)
```

Comment: The accuracy of this answer is highly dependant upon WHAT order he wants, which he has not actually defined so I am not sure why it is getting upvoted so quickly. I mean, fair enough there is a 90% chance he wants asc but still...

Comment: Fair enough - if you want the opposite, you can use `arsort()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) or pass the array to `array_reverse()` after it is sorted - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Don't forget usort() as well, he might be looking for a custom sort as well based upon teh values.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply. Both of you! However, I would like to sort by numerical values so in the example above, 'canvasser' would be first, 'Canvasser' second, 'Sara' third etc. Do you know of a way to do this please?

Comment: Ha, looks like you were the 10%. You want to sort by `arsort()` to get the reverse of the example above.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `arsort($vals, SORT_NUMERIC);` because it's numeric...